# How to get the corresponding elements of a list in the data file quicker?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of some old IDs, for example, `list = [1, 2, 4, 7, 5]`.

I have a csv data file, which the third column is the old IDs and the fifth column is the corresponding new Id. what can I do to extract the new Id without reading the csv file every time for an element.

Now my plan is reading the csv every time for every element in the list, but it takes much time since the csv file is quite large.

```
id_list = []
for element in list:
    with open(path) as file:
        for row in file:
            if str(element) == row.split(",")[2]:
                id = int(row.split(",")[4])
                id_list.append(id)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Change to a random access storage like `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0):

A note about your program first. [id and list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) are reserved words in python. You should not use them as variable names.

That said, here is a possible solution (may be better off with a large csv file to load into a database as stovfl suggested - but that's another idea).

You could use the code below and it should get the results. (You should probably use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for working with csv files).

```
import csv

_list = [1, 2, 4, 7, 5]
old_id = set(_list) # using a set will get faster lookups

id_list = []
path = '/old_data/perlp/into.csv' # insert your path here


with open(path, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        old = row[2]
        if int(old) in old_id:
            new_id = int(row[4])
            id_list.append(new_id)
```

Comment: But would the elements in the output list are in correspondence order with respect to the original list?

Comment: @FrankQ No, it would be in the order that old ids appeared in the file. I am wondering why you need to get the order of the list?

Comment: Yes, I have thanked about it. I don't need the order. Cheers. @chris